# mysql 5.7 timestamp default insert null error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, timestamp, sql-insert

I have the following create table statement.

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` ( 
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`field1` varchar(10),
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

when I do the following insert, I'll get the erro "Column 'updated_at' cannot be null"

```
insert into test_table (id, field1, updated_at) values (1234, 'foo', null);
```

I expected `updated_at` would just take on the default value in this case.

mysql version 5.7.12

However when I do this in mysql version 5.6, the insert commands works.
Is there a change in the versoin from 5.6 to 5.7? The only difference I thought was 5.7 has NO_ZERO_DATE default to true. But I thought that was only for datetime. Is there a configuration change that I need to make?

It's possible to achieve the result by not passing in `updated_at` but I don't have over insert statement in this case.

Comment: updatwe your 5.7.12 to 5.7.31 that works perfectly see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b3682090bdb097bd66c248bf1daa4a6c

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is related to [SQL Strict mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict) - but I can't find the exact quote in the documentation that matches your use case.

Bottom line, you should not be expecting the server to use the default when you provide it with an explicit `null` value.

If you can't remove the column from the `insert` list for some reason, a possible workaround is to use the `default` keyword, which makes your intent unambiguous:

```
insert into test_table (id, field1, updated_at) 
values (1234, 'foo', default);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown because explicit_defaults_for_timestamp is enabled. Disabling this will solve the issue
Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp